# Hyperlinks on Grid

Tags: delphi

I'm just wondering if anyone has implemented
hyperlinks in grids. I got a grid with several 
columns i.e. Customers, Products, Contacts, 
Invoice etc etc. And I want to pop up a screen
depends on which cell it clicked on. I don't want
to simply trap on the OnCellClick event but
only when  text is clicked, like a url\hyperlink.
Same with hovering, I'd like the cursor to change
only when the mouse is on top of the text. Any
suggestion how to do this ?

Thanks !

Comment: what grid are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes, it has been done. For example TMS Software do a grid that can have HTML cell content, including link elements, and there are probably plenty of others. It depends on whether you want to spend money on a component, or try to build it yourself.